# Sharepoint application backup not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

when i try to take backup of share point application. first time it was fine.
later, it is showing "backup in progress" but no result after a long.
i delete the backup/restore process, i check the current running job , there was no job.

Answer (score 0):

Please take the backup and restore the SharePoint Application using Powershell command is very useful and effective.

It is the good manner to take this action.

Comment: This is what i was doing brother, and it was working only in the first time. if you want to take a backup again using the same manner, it wont work. anyway i could fix it and its fine now .Thanks